# Reading rainbow tables from freerainbowtables.com

Tags: cracking, network-security, rainbowtable, rainbowattack

I have downloaded Rainbow Tables from freerainbowtables.com. Its extension is .rti . I was wondering if there is a way to read this file as a text file or anyother file. I want to write a simple program to read this file and store its contents in a hashmap. I need to do this for a project of mine.

I tried googling and also went through the forums, but no luck so far. 
Any help/links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it helps what is written on their page:

> The tables are in a custom format to save disk space (50%!). To make use of them, use rcracki (rcrack improved) which can be downloaded from our download page
>   If you want original rainbowcrack tables to use with other programs than rcracki, then you can convert the tables using rti2rto which also can be found on our download page

(see: http://freerainbowtables.com/en/tables/)

I don't knwo if rto is any better for you than rti, but I'd suggest to give it a try.

Comment: I still cant figure out how to read .rt files. The softwares like Cain already have support for them, but it no where says how the contents of the file are organized, so that i can read them into my own data structures

Comment: You can explore source code of rcracki, it also avaliable from the side in download section

Answer (score 1):

You may check rainbow table file specification - http://project-rainbowcrack.com/file_format.htm

Answer (score 0):

RTI and RT is both binary formats and contains only 64 bit numbers. A 64 bit starting point and a 64 bit endingpoint.
The difference between RTI and RT is RTI packs the numbers while RT stores them in their raw format.
To find out how to extract the plaintexts from the RT files, I suggest you take a look at rtdump (google it)